# How to make AlarmBootReceiver send notification at specified time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

I have an AlarmResiver class, it sends notifications if the user has set the time and the toggle switch is on. But this class is bad in that when the device reboots, notifications are no longer received. Then I decided to create an AlarmBootResiver class that will send notifications after the device is rebooted. Now this class is working, but it sends notifications immediately after turning on the device. How to make the AlarmBootResiver send notifications at the time set by the user in the AlarmResiver class ?

AlarmActivity code:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private EditText mondayText;
    public SwitchCompat mondaySwitch;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String timeText = "";
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    boolean switch_On_Off;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Switch_On_Off_check";
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        mondayText = findViewById(R.id.monday_time);
        mondaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch_monday);
        // load SharedPref save text in mondayText and save switch On else Off
        loadText();
        loadSwitchCheck();

        mondaySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (mondaySwitch.isChecked()) {
                    startAlarm(c);
                    bootStartAlarm(c);
                }
                saveSwitchCheck();
            }
        });

        mondayText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        updateTimeText(c);
        saveText();
        mondaySwitch.setChecked(false);
        bootStopAlarm(c);
    }

    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {
        timeText = "";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
        mondayText.setText(timeText);
    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void bootStartAlarm(Calendar c) {

        PackageManager packageManager = AlarmActivity.this.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void bootStopAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        PackageManager packageManager = AlarmActivity.this.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

My AlertReciever

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
    }
}
```

My AlarmBootReciever

```
public class AlarmBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
            NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification();
            notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

My NotificationHelper

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    public static final String channelID = "channelID";
    public static final String channelName = "Channel Name";

    private NotificationManager mManager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (mManager == null) {
            mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return mManager;
    }

    public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DashBoardActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
                .setContentTitle("ЭЙ ТЫ!")
                .setContentText("Пора на тренировку!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_training)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` for this. This code will work, even if you restart your device or lock the device, the `PowerManager` does that for you. See here for more information https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(YOUR DRAWABLE)
                            .setContentTitle("YOUR TITLE")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500)
                            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
                            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setContentText("THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE NOTIFICATION");

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
            wakeLock.acquire();

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// mNotificationId is a unique integer your app uses to identify the
// notification. For example, to cancel the notification, you can pass its ID
// number to NotificationManager.cancel().
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }
}
```

You can trigger AlarmReceiver using this in `MainActivity` for example where you can set your time of trigger, see comment.

```
 public void doNotification() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


// InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption //ms, s, min
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, pending); //every month
    }
```

Comment: what do you suggest me to use? Everything works fine for me. I need to set the notification response time after rebooting the device in AlertBootResiver the same time as in AlertResiver

Comment: Do you want to send notification in a certain amount of time? Like every 60 seconds, or what is your intention?

Comment: My application sends notifications at the specified time regularly. But when the device reboots or turns off, notifications no longer work. Therefore, I added an AlarmBootResiver to the application, but it sends a notification immediately after turning on the device. I want to set the time for sending a notification after turning on the device the same as in the AlarmResiver

Comment: If you use my code then the notifications will also work when you reboot

Comment: You suggest me to change all the code that I have. And I need to fix the piece of code that I have. Why should I rewrite all the code?

Comment: No,look at the second part of my code. You can set the time manually

Comment: Check this one here: alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, pending); //every month

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198494/discussion-between---and-blnpwr).